# Split $\{1,2,...,n\}$ into $k$ subsets so that the sum of the elements in each subset are as close as possible.

Tags: discrete-optimization, set-partition, np-complete

Let $S_i,i=1,...,k$ to be the sum of elements in subset $k$, I want to minimize $\max_i S_i - \min_i S_i$. I have thought about some greedy method but they are not optimal. I know that partition problem is NPC. I wonder if my problem is NP-hard or can be solved in polynomial time. Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning

Comment: The base set here is quite special, the problem might be a lot easier.